# How to make a function that will calculate the area under the curve of the graph using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, integral, calculus

I need to make the function so that it calculate the area when I enter function f and coefficients a, b and n on the command line.

For now I have this:

```
module.exports = function (f,a,b,n,next) {

parseFloat(a);
parseFloat(b);
parseInt(n);
var h = (b-a)/n;
var s = 0;
var suma = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        var ximj = a+h*(i-1);
        var xi = a+h*i;
        var x = (ximj + xi)/2;
        s += eval(f,x);
    }
    return s;
};

if (n<1) {
    next(new Error("Koeficijent n je broj ekvidistantnih točaka."))
}
else next(null, {povrsina : function () {return h*suma();}}
    );
```

I think that the function `suma()` isn't working like it should be working.

In command line this should be look like :

```
f: x*x-2*x+7
a: 2
b: 4
n: 10
Povrsina ispod grafa funkcije f je 20.66000...
```

My prompt file looks like this:

```
var pov = require('./integrator.js');

var prompt = require('prompt');

prompt.get (['f','a','b','n'],function (err,koef) {
if (err) return console.log(err);
console.log("f: ",koef.f);
console.log("a: ",koef.a);
console.log("b: ",koef.b);
console.log("n: ",koef.n);

parseFloat(koef.a);
parseFloat(koef.b);
parseInt(koef.n);

pov(koef.f,koef.a,koef.b,koef.n,function(err,rj){
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else 
        console.log("Povrsina ispod grafa funkcije f je " + rj.povrsina());
});
```

Thank you for help :)

Comment: First of all you use parseInt and parseFloat wrong. Those functions do not mutate variables. They just return parsed value. You have to use them like this: `a = parseFloat(a);`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to calculate the area under a curve you are going to need to provide a lower and upper x limit, otherwise the answer will always be infinite. Personally I use [this function that I wrote](https://gist.github.com/jgphilpott/4276345a5b7c96fc010afa28cc5d38b6):

```
function findArea(lowerLimit, upperLimit, coefficients) {

  let lower = 0
  let upper = 0

  for (let i = 0; i < coefficients.length; i++) {

    lower += (coefficients[i] * Math.pow(lowerLimit, i + 1)) / (i + 1)
    upper += (coefficients[i] * Math.pow(upperLimit, i + 1)) / (i + 1)

  }

  return Math.abs(upper - lower)

}
```

If you pass in two numbers as the limits and an array of coefficients in the format, *a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3* ... and so on, you will get the correct answer. For example, say you have the equation *y = 5 + 4x + 3x^2 + 2x^3* and you want to find the area under the curve between *x = 1* and *x = 3* you can call this function like so, `findArea(1, 3, [5, 4, 3, 2])` and you will get the answer `92` which represents the number of units squared. Keep in mind that this works only if the area you are evaluating is either entirely above or entirely below the x axis. **If your area crosses the x axis you will need to calculate the area above and below separately!**

You can check the results against the [Symbolab Area Under The Curve Calculator](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/area-under-curve-calculator) but this should work for any curve.

Answer (score 0):

The [`eval` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) reads a string and evaluates it. If you want to evaluate the function `f` with the parameter `x`, then you can just write `f(x)` instead of calling `eval()`. This is because, in JavaScript, [functions are first-class values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) and can be passed around just like numbers, strings, and so on.

In `suma`, particularly the line `var ximj = a+h*(i-1);`, your for-loop multiplies `h` by -1, then by 0, then by 1. I suspect you meant `var ximj = a+h*(i+1);` since `h` is the width of your differential. But that would only produce small errors.

As Lends wrote, you also need to correct your `Parse*` calls:

```
a = parseFloat(a);
b = parseFloat(b);
n = parseInt(n);
```

Comment: If you wanted to keep the current function argument as a string you could do `(new Function("x","return " + f))(x)` to turn it into a function and immediately execute it.

Comment: I do not condone using JavaScript as its own preprocessor. The asker should write a function to be passed in as `f`. What if an `f` string is malformed? Then you're borked. Make it easy, just don't use `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [math.js](http://mathjs.org/) to eval a string math expression, for example:

```
var math = require('mathjs');

var integral = function(f, a, b, n, next) {
    a = parseFloat(a);
    b = parseFloat(b);
    n = parseInt(n);
    var h = (b - a) / n;
    var s = 0;
    var suma = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            var ximj = a + h * (i - 1);
            var xi = a + h * i;
            var x = (ximj + xi) / 2;
            s += math.eval(f, { x: x });
        }

        return s;
    };

    if (n < 1) {
        next(new Error("Koeficijent n je broj ekvidistantnih točaka."))
    } else {
        next(null, { povrsina: function() { return h * suma(); } });
    }
};

var f = 'x * x - 2 * x + 7';
var a = '2';
var b = '4';
var n = '10000';

integral(f, a, b, n, function(err, rj) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log("Povrsina ispod grafa funkcije f je " + rj.povrsina());
});

/* output:
Povrsina ispod grafa funkcije f je 20.66806662000201
*/
```

You integral function seems to have an has an issue though, n must be very high to get near the expected result (like 10000). Or is it supposed to work that way? For n = 10, it gives 22 for example.

Another solution is to use an [existing package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/integrate-adaptive-simpson) or at least read the source code to get an idea.

Comment: It's 22 because my for-loop start at 0 but it should be starting at 1 and than I get near the expected result.

Comment: @DraganaOstopanj Ok, my math skill is rusty :p With i starts at 1, it gives the correct result with n = 10.